# How to setup if statement option to make it working whenever I select 2?

Tags: c, if-statement

In this code **if-statement** is giving me problem. Whenever I try to select option 2, it didn't give me the message of **selected 2**? How to make working this if statement working?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void hello(){
    int option;
    static const char * listing[] = {"Name", "Date of birth","ID card number"};
    FILE * fr3 = fopen("file.txt","r");

    if (fr3 == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to read text file.");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (option = 1; option <= sizeof(listing)/sizeof(char *); ++option)
       printf("%d. Your %s\n", option, listing[option-1]);  

    fputs("Select your choice to update: ", stdout);   
    if (scanf("%d", &option) == 1) {
        puts("selected 1");
        fclose(fr3);
        exit(0);
    }
    if (scanf("%d", &option) == 2) {
        puts("selected 2");
        fclose(fr3);
        exit(0);
    }
      fclose(fr3);
}
int main(){ hello(); }
```

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of items parsed.

Comment: And calling `scanf` twice means two inputs are needed. You should call `scanf` once and then use the conditional checks on the `option` value.

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: Please see [scanf's manpage](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/scanf.3.html) before posting such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have shifted `scanf("%d", &option)` outside if statement. So, please check below code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void hello(){
    int option;
    static const char * listing[] = {"Name", "Date of birth","ID card number"};
    FILE * fr3 = fopen("file.txt","r");

    if (fr3 == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to read text file.");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    for (option = 1; option <= sizeof(listing)/sizeof(char *); ++option)
       printf("%d. Your %s\n", option, listing[option-1]);  
    
    fputs("Select your choice to update: ", stdout);   
    scanf("%d", &option);
    if (option == 1) {
        puts("selected 1");
        fclose(fr3);
        exit(0);
    }
    if (option == 2) {
        puts("selected 2");
        fclose(fr3);
        exit(0);
    }
      fclose(fr3);
}
int main(){ hello(); }
```

Comment: You should always check return value of `scanf`.

Comment: There are some bugs in the code but the main concern was with `scanf` so I suggested him implement it in that way.

Comment: Might be true but the main error in the original code was misunderstanding what `scanf` returns. Showing proper use of that return value would IMHO provide extra value to the OP.